# How can I typeset the math symbol with a circle and a rectangle attached to it?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to use a math-symbol, which looks like the following picture (a circle with a rectangle attached to it). Is there a package which provides such or if not, how can I create it by myself?

[image: mystery symbol]

I tried using [detextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) but did not get any satisfying result.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Does the symbol have a name?

Comment: @Bobyandbob OP said detexify didn't list an appropriate symbol. Are you saying to keep trying, because you found it using detexify?

Comment: Is this symbol your ad hoc invention, or did you find it in some math publication? What should it denote?

Comment: Have you searched through the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf)?

Comment: I did not find it in any publication. It will denote a geometric construction in work in progress of mine since the construction resembles the symbol in a simplified case.

Comment: Yes, I searched through the Comprehensive List. No, I'm not aware of an established name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without additional guidance, I made it based on `\circ` and defined it as `\mathbin`.

For a version that only works in the regular math size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\mathkey{%
  \mathbin{\stackinset{r}{-.98pt}{c}{.3pt}{%
    \def\stackalignment{l}%
    \stackon[-.85pt]{\rule{2pt}{1.2pt}}{\textcolor{white}{\rule{1.65pt}{0.45pt}}}%
  }{$\circ$}\kern1.2pt}%
}
\begin{document}
$A\mathkey B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the version that works across math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\mathkey{%
  \mathbin{\scalerel*{\stackinset{r}{-.98pt}{c}{.3pt}{%
    \def\stackalignment{l}%
    \stackon[-.85pt]{\rule{2pt}{1.2pt}}{\textcolor{white}{\rule{1.65pt}{0.45pt}}}%
  }{$\circ$}\kern1.2pt}{\circ}}%
}
\begin{document}
$A\mathkey B$

$\scriptstyle A\mathkey B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\mathkey B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the final `\circ` in the definition of `\mathkey` defines the vertical footprint of the `\mathkey` symbol.  Thus, one could change that to something else, let's say `X`, in order to enlarge the resulting `\mathkey`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\mathkey{%
  \mathbin{\scalerel*{\stackinset{r}{-.98pt}{c}{.3pt}{%
    \def\stackalignment{l}%
    \stackon[-.85pt]{\rule{2pt}{1.2pt}}{\textcolor{white}{\rule{1.65pt}{0.45pt}}}%
  }{$\circ$}\kern1.2pt}{X}}%
}
\begin{document}
$A\mathkey B$

$\scriptstyle A\mathkey B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\mathkey B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Prepare a `keyhole.mp` file containing

```
beginfig(1);
w=18pt;
h=10pt;
o=1pt;
r=h/2;
pickup pencircle scaled 1pt;
lft z1=(o,r);
top z2=(r+o,h);
bot z4=(r+0,0);
rt z3=(2r+o,h/2);
path circlepart;
circlepart=z1..z2..z3..z4..cycle;
z5=point 2-1/4 of circlepart;
z6=(w-o,y5);
z7=(w-o,y8);
z8=point 2+1/4 of circlepart;
draw z1..z2..z5--z6--z7--z8..z4..cycle;
endfig;
end.
```

This is inspired from “lightbulb” in the Comprehensive List of LaTeX symbols.

Run `mptopdf keyhole.mp`, which will produce a file with name `keyhole-1.pdf`.

Now the LaTeX test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\keyhole}{%
  \mathrel{\text{\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`X]{keyhole-1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\keyhole B_{\keyhole}$

\end{document}
```

It would be possible to define different figures with different line thickness for the smaller sizes.

[image]